# How to enable sbt-scalabuff in a Play2 application?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm trying to use sbt-scalabuff to generate scala case class from proto file. I have added the plugin reference into plugins.sbt file of the Play project, added runtime dependencies too.

If I do not add any settings to Build.scala referring to sbt-scalabuff then I assume that will go with default settings, expecting to find the files in src/main/protobuf.

Do you know any Build.scala sample of proper settings of sbt-scalabuff?

Thanks,
Gabi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tested sbt-scalabuff much myself, but you can try raising an issue on the sbt-scalabuff github page.